# вывести двумерный массив спиралью

Tags: java, массивы

в задаче ниже нужно написать метод, которому передается два значения для двумерного массива, а именно кол-во строк и кол-во столбцов. этот метод должен заполнить массив так, чтобы когда его выводишь на экран, числа шли спиралью и по часовой стрелке:

```
1   2   3 

10  11   4

9  12   5

8   7   6
```

сама задача:

**`int[][] spiral(int rows, int columns)`

Возвращает двумерный массив в виде таблицы, содержащий числа от 1 до rows * columns. Размер таблицы будет определяться заданными параметрами.
Числа заполняют "таблицу" по часовой стрелке от верхнего угла по спирали.**

подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, что пошло не так в моем решении

```java
static int[][] spiral(int rows, int columns) {

        int[][] spiral = new int[rows][columns];

        int sum = rows * columns;
        int x = rows;
        int y = columns;

        int counter = 1;

        rows += 1;
        columns +=1;

        do {

            rows -= 1;
            columns -=1;
            // должен по идее передавать значение первой строки
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++){
                for (int a = 0; a < columns - 1; a ++){

                    spiral[i][a] = counter;
                    counter++;
                }

            }
            // а этот по идее последнего столбца
            for (int i = columns-1; i < columns; i ++){
                for (int a = 0; a < rows - 1; a ++){
                    spiral[a][i] = counter;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            //а этот самой нижней строки и так далее
            for (int i = rows - 1; i < rows; i++){
                for (int a = columns - 1; a < 0; i--){
                    spiral[i][a] = counter;
                    counter ++;
                }
            }

        } while (counter < sum);


        return spiral;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись и без излишних двойных вложенных циклов `for` внутри цикла `do-while`.  Следует завести переменные для верхней/нижней строки и правого/левого столбца и реализовать четыре цикла для прохождения по спирали вправо/вниз/влево/вверх, пока не будет достигнуто максимальное значение `rows * cols`:

```java
public static int[][] spiral(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] arr = new int[rows][cols];
    
    int num = 1;
    int max = rows * cols;
    
    int rmin = 0, rmax = rows - 1;
    int cmin = 0, cmax = cols - 1;
    
    while (num <= max) {
        // проход влево по верхней строке, инкремент столбцов
        for (int i = cmin; num <= max && i <= cmax; i++) {
            arr[rmin][i] = num++;
        }
        rmin++;
        // проход вниз по правому краю, инкремент строк
        for (int i = rmin; num <= max && i <= rmax; i++) {
            arr[i][cmax] = num++;
        }
        cmax--;
        // проход вправо по нижней строке, декремент столбцов
        for (int i = cmax; num <= max && i >= cmin; i--) {
            arr[rmax][i] = num++;
        }
        rmax--;
        // проход вверх по левому краю, декремент строк
        for (int i = rmax; num <= max && i >= rmin; i--) {
            arr[i][cmin] = num++;
        }
        cmin++;
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println("-- 5 x 4 --");
for (int[] row : spiral(5, 4)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

```
-- 5 x 4 --
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[14, 15, 16, 5]
[13, 20, 17, 6]
[12, 19, 18, 7]
[11, 10, 9, 8]
```